# Babel does not transpile a JSX instance of an arrow function

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, arrow-functions

my Javascript & React level is beginner.

I'm having fun with https://babeljs.io/repl to see how my JSX is transpiled into an older version of Javascript, and there is something I don't quite understand.

I'm trying to use an arrow function and an instance of this function :

```
const App = () => {
    return <div></div>;
}

<App></App>
```

Which throws me an error :

```
repl: Unexpected token (5:6)
  3 | }
  4 | 
> 5 | <App></App>
    |       ^
```

Note that a normal function AND it's instance () is working fine. An arrow function ONLY is working fine too. The problem happens when i use an arrow function AND the JSX instanciation of it.

Thank you !!

Comment: @Sulthan They are allowed wherever you wish. JSX is just syntactic sugar for `createElement`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem happens when i use an arrow function AND the JSX instanciation of it.

That's the problem here. In order to be parsed correctly, `<App></App>` should be unambiguously identified as JSX. This cannot be done because a semicolon after an arrow was omitted.

It [should be](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAggBwTAvDAFASlQPhgbwCgYSYAnAUygFcywYAeAEwEsA3HBgelY4G5CAXwGEGiBJy7icQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact&prettier=true&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=):

```
const App = () => {
    return <div></div>;
};

<App></App>
```

As another answer mentions, JSX syntax is usually used in situations like `ReactDOM.render(...)` where it can be unambiguously identified as an expression, so this problem won't occur in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Please also note that having `<App></App>` on file-level scope - while being technically correct - will result in discarding a value that it produces - no component will be mounted. Usually, one would use ReactDOM's render method to render React components' tree:

```
const root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root)
```